# how to view sparse matrix which has self connecting node

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to view my sparse matrix with the function

```
view(biograph(CM,[],'ShowWeights','on')).
```

But it shows me

> Warning: Self connecting nodes are not allowed, ignoring the diagonal of CM. 
>   In biograph.biograph at 158

Answer (score 0):

If `CM` is your adjecency matrix, then the self connecting nodes are on the nodes on the diagonal, i.e. the weights of the path from `i` to `i` for some `i`.

To check whether you have self connecting nodes just check the diagonal entries:

```
any(full(diag(CM)) ~=0)
```